# Wordpress ACF Relationships in custom posts

Tags: php, wordpress, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

I've got multiple custom post types. Recipes and Ingredients. Recipe page contains ACF Relationship field to select ingredients. Ingredients custom posts belong to specific categories "Vegetables", "Meat"... On Ingredients Archive pages I would like to list recipes that consist of ingredients from the current category. Any help or directions would be appreciated.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'recipes',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'ingredient_name', // custom field name
        'value' => '"' . get_terms('ingredients_categories') . '"', // assuming that this is getting post's categories
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
```

);

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. I resolved this problem like this

for example you have custom field ingredients_field. This field is Multiple Select and in database it looks like this:

meta_key = ingredients_field_0 meta_value = 'some id of ingredient'
meta_key = ingredients_field_1 meta_value = 'some another id of ingredient'
....

so, you need to find this key.
for example you can add like this:

```
$current_ingredient_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;

for($counter = 10; $counter < 10; $counter++ ){
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'ingredients_field_' . $current_ingredient_id,
        'value'   => $item,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
}

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'recipes',
'meta_query' => $meta_query,
)
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

PS: I know this isn't perfect solution but it worked for me.

PPS: I'm not sure that keys in db builds like I wrote for you. Try to find in wp_postmeta table keys like yours

Comment: Hi Danil, thanks for your response. Am I understanding it correctly, your suggested solution is for multiple entries in "relationship" field? In my case, I'm having a singular entry as I'm using a repeater on a post to list ingredients as I need to attach details to them for example "Cauliflower"(ingredients post) and "100g"(detail). The idea is to pull recipe posts onto "Vegetables" ingredients taxonomy page if recipe posts feature "Cauliflower" as an item in them. "Cauliflower" is a post from custom post type(ingredients) with a category "Vegetables".

Comment: No matter how you saving this filed repeater or relationship. What I want to say is, try to find this meta filed in database (for understanding how it looks in db) and then build your meta query.

Comment: Hi Danil, for some reason it results in displaying all of the recipes. 
`
'key'     => 'field_5ee07090408b3' . $current_ingredient_id,
`

Comment: I think, my description is not right, as the pages, these recipes are being pulled on are ingredients taxonomy pages.  Dairy, Meat, Fish...